# Solving a Quadratic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x) = 9x^2 - 48x + 14$

I need help in solving this equation.

I cannot simply factorise it, so do I need to use the 'quadratic' formula  to solve it?

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/quadraticeq/complsquare/complsquare.html

Comment: Well, then go on with the quadratic formula. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

$$\Delta:=b^2-4ac=48^2-4\cdot 9\cdot 14=1800=2\cdot 900\implies$$

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{48\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2\cdot 9}=\frac{48\pm 30\sqrt2}{18}=\frac{8\pm5\sqrt2}3$$

Comment: Thanks everyone for getting back to me so soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can factorise it like this:

$9x^2-48x+14=(9x^2-48x+64)-50=(3x-8)^2-50=(3x-8)^2-(5\sqrt{2})^2=$

$=(3x-8+5\sqrt{2})\cdot(3x-8-5\sqrt{2})$

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do in this situation, is to check for the discriminant i.e. $$D = b^2-4ac$$

This will tell us, if the your question has a solution or not. If the number is less than zero, then it has no roots. If it is greater than zero then it has two roots and if it equal to zero then it is has one root.

So we have the following:
\begin{align}
&D = b^2-4ac \\
&D = (-48)^2 - 4(9)(14) \\
&D = 1800
\end{align}

Great! This equation has  two roots. Now that we already have the discriminant, we can just use the quadratic formula

$$\begin{align}
&x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\
&x = \frac{-9 \pm \sqrt{1800}}{18} \quad \text{*}\\
\end{align}$$

(*) Remember that $b^2-4ac$ is really just $D$ which we calculated before hand and so we can just sub that in.

Now if you work that last bit out, you should get the following roots:

$$x = \frac{1}{3} (8-5\sqrt{2}) \text{ or } \frac{1}{3} (8+5\sqrt{2}) $$

Answer (score 0):

$$9x^2-48x+14=0,$$ $$x_1=\frac{8+5\sqrt 2}{3}; x_2=\frac{8-5\sqrt 2}{3}$$

The factorise it:

$$9x^2-48x+14=9\left(x-\frac{8+5\sqrt 2}{3}\right)\left(x+\frac{8-5\sqrt 2}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

$$f(x) = 9x^2 - 48x + 14=(3x)^2-2\cdot3x\cdot8+8^2-8^2+14=$$
$$=(3x-8)^2-50=(3x-8)^2-(\sqrt50)2=$$
$$=(3x-3\frac{8}{3}-3\frac{\sqrt50}{3})(3x-3\frac{8}{3}+3\frac{\sqrt50}{3})=$$
$$=9(x-\frac{8}{3}-\frac{\sqrt50}{3})(x-\frac{8}{3}+\frac{\sqrt50}{3})=$$
$$=9\left(x-\frac{8+5\sqrt2}{3}\right)\left(x-\frac{8-5\sqrt2}{3}\right)$$